# Complex exponent $(z^{\frac{m}{n}})^{\frac{n}{m}}$

Tags: complex-analysis

It clear that $(z^{\frac{m}{n}})^{\frac{n}{m}}\neq1$ ($m,n$ are irreducible positive integers ) as left hand side is not a singleton. If we solve it as $(z^{\frac{m}{n}})^{\frac{n}{m}}$ we get $m$ values and if we solve like $(z^{\frac{n}{m}})^{\frac{m}{n}}$ it gives $n$ values. How to solve it? Please suggest the right way. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You've pretty much done the work.  If you look at $(z^{1/2})^{2/1}$ you get a single answer, since 
$$ z^{1/2} = (re^{i\theta})^{1/2} = \{ \sqrt{r}e^{i\theta/2}, ~ \sqrt{r}e^{i\theta/2+i\pi} \} $$
and squaring we get
$$ (z^{1/2})^{2/1} = re^{i\theta} $$ for both possible roots.

On the other hand, 
$$ z^2 = r^2e^{i2\theta}$$
and taking a square root we have
$$ (z^2)^{1/2} = \{ re^{i\theta}, ~ re^{i\theta + i\pi} \}. $$

This shows that your values of $(z^{m \over n})^{n\over m}$ and $(z^{n\over m})^{m\over n}$ **will in general be different**, just like you stated in your question.  I.e., power functions do not commute.

Accepting this, $(z^{m\over n})^{n\over m}$ has the $m$ values $\{ re^{i\theta + i2\pi k/m } \}$ for $k = 0, 1, \dots, m-1$ where $z = re^{i\theta}$.

Comment: its means we look as it is written, do not commute power?

Comment: Yes! Without restricting yourself to a single (specific) branch of each root function, you cannot commute the fractions.